# $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ is Banach space iff $\mathcal{Y}$ is Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Taken from Conway's A course in Functional Analysis Chapter 3 Section 2 Problem 1

Problem Statement: Show that for $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X}, \mathbb{F})\neq (0)$, $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ is a Banach space if and only if $\mathcal{Y}$ is a Banach space.

In the forward direction, we suppose that $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X}, \mathbb{F})$ is a Banach space. Then $\{T_n\} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X}, \mathbb{F})$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore it converges to $T\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X}, \mathbb{F})$. This means that $\sup\{||(T_n - T)(x)||: ||x|| = 1\} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Now consider a sequence $y_n \in \mathcal{Y}$. We hope to show that this sequence converges to $y\in \mathcal{Y}$. If I can write $y_n = T_n(x)$ then since $T_n$ is Cauchy, it must follow that $T_n(x)$ converges to some $y \in \mathcal{Y}$. But I'm not sure how to make this clear.

Any tips is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Sketch (fill in the details):

Suppose $(T_n)$ is Cauchy in $B(X,Y)$. Then $(T(x)_n)$ is Cauchy in $Y$ for every $x\in X\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} T_n(x) = y_x.$ This defines a map $x\mapsto y_x$, which is evidently linear. Furthermore, $\|T_m(x)-T_n(x)\|\le \|T_m-T_n\|\|x\|\le \epsilon \|x\|$ if $m,n$ are large enough. Let $m\to \infty$. Then, $\|T-T_n\|\le \epsilon $, which shows that $T_n\to T$ and that since $T-T_n\in B(X,Y)$ so $T=T_n+T-T_n$ is, too.

Now, suppose $(y_n)$ Cauchy. First choose a $\phi\in X^*$ and an $x_0\in X$  such that $\phi(x_0)=1.$ For each $y\in Y$, define a map $g_y:X\to Y:x\mapsto \phi(x)y$ and show that $(g_{y_n})\subseteq B(X,Y)$ is Cauchy and therefore $g_{y_n}\to g\in B(X,Y)$. Finally, show that $y_n\to g(x_0).$